# [M,N]≅ [M,R] ⊗ N for E-infinity modules

Tags: homotopy-theory, traces, ring-spectra

Let $\texttt{R}$ be an $\texttt{E}$-infinity ring and let $\texttt{M,N}$ be $\texttt{E}$-infinity modules. Under what conditions do we have

$$ \texttt{[M, N] ≅ [M,R] ⊗ N}$$

Under ordinary circumstances (with modules), we can show that a canonical map is an isomorphism using rank or dimension. What is the easiest approach here?

One application is to the (higher) trace $\mathbb{Tr}$:

$$ \texttt{R → [M, M] → [M,R] ⊗ M → R}.$$

Comment: Why do you set your equations in `\texttt`?

Comment: @LSpice Because my work is in Lean 4 not just latex.

Comment: @LSpice, For instance, to write ⊗ I type ":tensor" which produces the unicode symbol using Dash for MacOSX but also makes perfectly good lean code for my spectra. On the Xetex I write "\newunicodechar{⊗}{$\otimes$}" in the preamble. Most Lean users use VS code, but my setup extracts the lean code from the tex file and compiles it separately from the terminal, producing lean's feedback next to the latex feedback.

Comment: @LSpice The texttt doesn't actually translate to proper lean code but it matches the font choice for tcolorbox from which the lean code is extracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See page 70 of EKMM. The map $$F_R(M,N) \wedge_R F_R(M',N') \rightarrow F_R(M \wedge_R M', N \wedge_R N')
$$ is an isomorphism if $M,M'$ are strongly dualizable or if $M$ is strongly dualizable and $N=R$. Being strongly dualizable is equivalent to being a wedge summand of a finite cell $R$ module.

Comment: I'm sure any expert knows, but I'm not an expert.  Could you say what EKMM is?

Comment: @LSpice Elemendorff Kriz May Mandell.